# Who is the uniformed guy in this Owarimonogatari end card?

Tags: monogatari-series

This is the end card for episode 11 of *Owarimonogatari*. (Click for larger image.)

[image: Episode 11 end card]

Who is the guy left of Shinobu, in some sort of uniform?

I tried searching, but the most information I got was from [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/01/02-1/monogatari-anime-site-offers-a-look-back-at-owarimonogatari-end-cards), which seems to have only listed the *artists* and *other* works they are famous for. (In the case of ep. 2, the title associated with the author is obviously related to the content of the end card, but this isn't true of most of the others. I did try looking up *Human Crossing*, but wasn't able to find a character who looked blatantly similar to the guy I'm curious about. This might be, however, because I don't know anything about the series.)

Comment: I thought this was the samurai guy before he got turned into a suit of armor. Like he's Shinobu's "number one" guy and Araragi's the second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tlM3.jpg) to a college-aged Kosaku Shima, the titular character of Kenshi Hirokane's [*Student Kosaku Shima*](http://evening.moae.jp/lineup/340) series.

College students in the [Showa era](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/video/waseda-university-department-of-engineering-mobilized-news-footage/505527691) wore uniforms like this. This uniform and emblem is specific to Waseda University, Kosaku Shima's alma mater.

[image: 早稲田大学の入学式に現れた島耕作]
[image: 早稲田大学の入学式に現れた島耕作]

The public Twitter for the series even made a tweet about the end card: https://twitter.com/shimakosaku1966/status/675702573433663488